# Elasticsearch and the use of wildcard in the message element

Tags: elasticsearch

I am having difficulty with searching for a partial search in the message element of my elasticsearch messages.
I copied an extract of a message below. Now I have the following and tried other searches for the "Process*"-query (termQuery, wildcardQuery, with a star, without a star) but to no success. 
Can you help me out

Code:

```
QueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
           .must(termQuery("environment", "dev"))
           .must(termQuery("message", "ProcessOrder*"));

SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("logstash-2015.07.08")
                 .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_AND_FETCH)
                 .setQuery(qb)
                 .execute()
                 .actionGet();
```

ES _source:

```
{
    "@timestamp": "2015-07-08T09:59:34.699Z",
    "@version": "1",
    "environment": "dev",
    "file": "/#####/server.log",
    "host": "#######",
    "instance": "####",
    "message": "10:59:32,566 DEBUG ExternalOrderMessage=<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>\n<ns2:ProcessOrderFulfilmentMessage>#####\n</ns2:ProcessOrderFulfilmentMessage>\n",
    "offset": [],
    "tags": ["multiline"],
    "type": "jboss"
}
```

Comment: May you share index mapping?

Comment: The mapping is around 2000 lines in pretty JSON and I am not sure if I'm allowed to send it. What am I looking for?

Comment: I'm interested in mapping for `message` field. It's analyzed or not?

Comment: I have the following mappings for message and environment:
"environment": {
    "fields": {
        "raw": {
            "ignore_above": 256,
            "index": "not_analyzed",
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "norms": {
        "enabled": false
    },
    "type": "string"
},
"message": {
    "fields": {
        "raw": {
            "ignore_above": 256,
            "index": "not_analyzed",
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "norms": {
        "enabled": false
    },
    "type": "string"
},

Comment: When I search for environment=dev only the search is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to change term query to [query string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_wildcards) query in case you are interested in searching with wildcard.

```
{
    "query": {
        "query_string": {
           "default_field": "message",
           "query": "processorde*"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am still learning in elasticsearch, can I do this in my searchquery in java or is this a setting in the mapping?

Comment: @Jurn query string is just another [type of query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/query-dsl-queries.html) available in ES. You should be able to create this query by calling `QueryBuilders.queryString(..)`. Hope it helps.